# Could not find function WDIsearch?

Tags: r

install.packages("WDI")

install.packages("dplyr")

install.packages("ggplot2")

install.packages("ggrepl")

install.packages("scales")

data.list.GDP<-WDIsearch("gdp")

Error in WDIsearch("gdp") : could not find function "WDIsearch"

I'm recieving this error after installing WDI package and also reinstalled latest RStudio?
Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You must `library` in your packages after installing them:

```
library(WDI)
```

Comment: I thought I ran the library! sometimes we don't find simple things in front of us. Thanks very much for clarifying.

Comment: @Supraa, no problem. You need to library your packages in each time you open R!